# How to update value of stdClass with another stdClass nested property in PHP

Tags: php, stdclass

I have two nested stdClass (multiple values).

```
$object1 = json_decode ('{"key":"value", "emailing":{"live":false, "test":true}}')

$object2 = json_decode ('{"key":"value", "params:{"emailing":{"live":false, "test":true}, "esp":"email"}}')
```

I want to change a property of first object with some property of second. Both are stdClasses, tested with is_object. 
However I can't copy value to first object.

```
$object1->emailing = $object2->params->emailing;
```

Where all are of type stdClass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue simply is that `$object2` is not an object, since `json_decode()` fails. You had an issue with unbalanced quoting chars in the json string. Below is the fixed version which works fine:

```
<?php    
$object1 = json_decode ('{"key":"value", "emailing":{"live":false, "test":true}}');
$object2 = json_decode ('{"key":"value", "params":{"emailing":{"live":false, "test":true}, "esp":"email"}}');

$object1->emailing = $object2->params->emailing;
print_r($object1);
```

The output is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [key] => value
    [emailing] => stdClass Object
        (
            [live] =>
            [test] => 1
        )

)
```

A good idea in such case always is to read the error message raised with your code: "Trying to get property of non-object". That clearly points out what the issue is. Also some basic error handling never is a bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

Actually You can :)
You have syntax error in `"params:{"emailing":` - it should be `"params":{"emailing":`

Try that:

```
$object1 = json_decode('{"key":"value", "emailing":{"live":false, "test":true}}');
$object2 = json_decode('{"key":"value", "params":{"emailing":{"live":"newvalue1", "test":"newvalue2"}, "esp":"email"}}');

// before
print_r($object1);

// after
$object1->emailing = $object2->params->emailing;
print_r($object1);
```